# Filter Kotlin collection of pairs so pair content is not null

Tags: kotlin, collections, nullable

I am looking for a way to filter a `List<Pair<T?, U?>>` to a `List<Pair<T, U>>`: I would like to ignore pairs containing null.

Works, but i need smartcasting, too:

```
fun <T, U> List<Pair<T?, U?>>.filterAnyNulls() = 
    filter { it.first != null && it.second != null }
```

Works, but ugly `!!`, and does not feel idiomatic at all

```
fun <T, U> List<Pair<T?, U?>>.filterAnyNulls() = mapNotNull {
    if (it.first == null || it.second == null) {
        null
    } else {
        Pair(it.first!!, it.second!!)
    }
}
```

Any nice solutions? And any more generic solutions? (Maybe even in classes which can be [deconstructed](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html), like triples or data classes?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution utilizes destructuring and smart casts and will do what you need without ugly `!!`:

```
fun <T, U> List<Pair<T?, U?>>.filterPairs(): List<Pair<T, U>> =
    mapNotNull { (t, u) ->
        if (t == null || u == null) null else t to u
    }
```

Comment: Ah, better than my filter/map 

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a good answer to this, unfortunately.

As you say, the `filter()` option gives a list of `Pair<T?, U?>` where the compiler still thinks the pair's values can be null even though we know they can't.

And the `mapNotNull()` option fixes that, but needs new `Pair` objects to be created, which is inefficient.  (The `!!` there are ugly, but I think this is one of the times when they're justified.  It's a shame that the compiler's smart casts aren't smart enough, but I understand that total type inference is an intractable problem, and it has to stop somewhere.)

I found a third option, which fixes both of those problems, but at the cost of an unsafe cast:

```
fun <T, U> List<Pair<T?, U?>>.filterNotNull()
    = mapNotNull{ it.takeIf{ it.first != null && it.second != null } as? Pair<T, U> }
```

Like the second option, this uses `mapNotNull()` to both filter and convert the pairs; however, it does a simple cast to tell the compiler that the type parameters are non-nullable.  This returns a `Pair<T, U>` so that the compiler knows the pair values cannot be null, and it avoids creating any new objects (apart from the overall list, of course).

However, it gives a compile-time warning about an unsafe cast.  It runs fine for me (Kotlin/JVM), but like all unsafe casts there's no guarantee it will work on all platforms or all future versions.  So it's not ideal.

All three options have drawbacks.  Perhaps the best overall is your second option; the code itself is a little ugly, and inefficient (creating new Pairs), but it's safe, will always work, and is nice to use.

(By the way, I think `filterNotNull()` would be a better name for this function.  In the standard library, filter functions seem to be named for what they *keep*, not what they drop, so `filterAnyNulls()` would give completely the wrong impression!)

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a function the convert `Pair<T?, U?>` to `Pair<T, U>?`. I need to put `first` and `second` into some variables to make the smart casting work. You could use `first?.let { t ->`  as well.

Something like this:

```
fun <T, U> Pair<T?, U?>.toNullablePair() {
    val t = first
    val u = second
    return if (t == null || u == null) null else t to u
}
```

Then you can create your filter-function using it:

```
fun <T, U> List<Pair<T?, U?>>.filterAnyNulls() = 
    mapNotNull { it.toNullablePair() }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a variation on your second suggestion really, but another option is to explicitly return the non-null types:

```
fun <T, U> List<Pair<T?, U?>>.filterAnyNulls(): List<Pair<T, U>> = this
    .filter { (a, b) -> a != null && b != null }
    .map { (a, b) -> a!! to b!! }
```

I was hoping that [contracts](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/contracts) might be the solution to avoid the `!!` shouting in the `map`, but it appears that they are still quite limited and nowhere near developed enough yet. I don't think there's a way to avoid the `!!` for now, at least until the compiler or contracts get smarter.

Comment: Didn't know about contracts, thanks for showing them to me :)